# How to have macOS always be muted upon being opened

Tags: macos, sleep, mute

An example of why this kind of thing is important. Say I'm watching a video on YouTube to fall asleep, and my computer powers off to conserve battery. I wake up and pack up my computer in the morning and go to school. When I get there, I plug in my computer and turn it on. I see the background of the fullscreen YouTube video, and immediately start spamming the mute button. While it is waking up, however, my computer manages to belt out a full ten seconds of sound before it finally starts decides to respond to my command for it to shut up.

I would like that to never happen again. and I am willing to let someone into the innermost workings of my OS to make the mute button respond exactly when I press it, even if it blocks the OS from doing anything else for 45 seconds. I don't know what would be involved in making this happen, but I am willing to sacrifice a LOT of QoL to make it happen.

Comment: There is a simple open source program called [AutoVolume](https://github.com/jesse-c/AutoVolume). When your MacBook sleeps, it will automatically set the volume to whatever level you choose.

Comment: Maybe stick a headphone jack into the headphone port.

Comment: that's a nice idea spiff, but ideally I wouldn't have to remember to do anything at all, since if I could remember to put the headphone jack in, I could remember to close whatever media was open in the first place.